# Is there a way to return a value after a Key Event?

Tags: java

I have this key binder:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  //does stuff
    InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(panel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "RightArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "LeftArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "UpArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "DownArrow");

    am.put("RightArrow", new ArrowAction("RightArrow"));
    am.put("LeftArrow", new ArrowAction("LeftArrow"));
    am.put("UpArrow", new ArrowAction("UpArrow"));
    am.put("DownArrow", new ArrowAction("DownArrow"));
   }

  class ArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private String cmd;

        public ArrowAction(String cmd) {
            this.cmd = cmd;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("LeftArrow")) {
                System.out.println("The left arrow was pressed!");
            } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("RightArrow")) {
                System.out.println("The right arrow was pressed!");
            } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("UpArrow")) {
                System.out.println("The up arrow was pressed!");
            } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("DownArrow")) {
                System.out.println("The down arrow was pressed!");
            }
        }
      }
```

I would like my program to know when I hit an arrow key(it already does), then return a value back to main and then wait again for another arrow press. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to return to main?

Comment: Because with each keypress the board updates (a square matrix). I send that matrix to a method that updates a JPanel and displays each movement on a frame.

Comment: Key events are just fired off whenever a key is pressed.. You have to implement Key listener on a Component and add the overrides methods . You can return whatever value you want then... Or just set some variable to that value.